# 500 Internal Server Error for Store Method

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am gettin an null reference exception inside the Controller on the line:

return await Store.GetSearchDTO();

The error in the console reads:

POST http://localhost:55471/api/GetSearchDTO 500 (Internal Server Error)

Error: Resolving failed with a reason `[object Object]`, but no `resolveFailed` provided for segment `Search`

Any insight on why this may be happening would be great.

Controller

```
namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Search")]
    public class Controller : ApiController
    {

        private Store _store;

        public Store Store
        {
            get
            {
                return _store ?? Request.GetOwinContext().Get<Store>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _store = value;
            }
        }
        public Controller()
        {

        }
        public Controller(Store store)
        {
            Store = store;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetSearchDTO")]
        public async Task<SearchDTO> GetSearchDTO()
        {
            return await Store.GetSearchDTO();
        }
    }
}
```

Store

```
        public async Task<SearchDTO> GetSearchDTO()
        {
            var toReturn = new SearchDTO();
            var assessment = await Db.Definitions.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToListAsync();
            var Types = await Db.Types.ToListAsync();
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            foreach(var assess in assessment)
            {
                var courseName = await Db.Courses.Where(x => x.Id == assess.CourseId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                toReturn.CourseIds[i] = courseName.Id;
                toReturn.CourseNames[i] = courseName.Name;
                toReturn.Names[i] = assess.Name;
                i++;
            }
            foreach(var type in Types)
            {
                toReturn.TypeIds[j] = type.Id;
                toReturn.Types[j] = type.Name;
            }

            toReturn.SectionFlag = true;

            return toReturn;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share more of the exception? And the inner exception if it has any?

Comment: Absolutely! one moment.....

Comment: If you get a null reference exception on the line `return await Store.GetAssessmentSearchDTO();` it means the property `Store` is null, and your `AssessmentStore` isn't being injected properly.

Comment: Interesting you are right it is null. Do you believe adding -- using OneApi.Models.Stores -- at the top would work?

Comment: After looking over it many times I cannot find where it's injected improperly

Comment: @RyeGuy, The problem is not the injection. `AssessmentStore` is not being injected via construct or via owin, as in the value is `null`. You need to register it and its dependencies with which ever DI framework or IoC container that is being used with the application because it is not being resolved.

Comment: Got it. You are absolutely correct. I really appreciate the insight!